# Describe scikit learn iris database

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I would like to describe the iris dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()
iris = pd.DataFrame(iris)

iris.describe()
```

But Python returned the following error code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-f1e3a89d050a> in <module>
      4 
      5 iris = datasets.load_iris()
----> 6 iris = pd.DataFrame(iris)
      7 
      8 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    466 
    467         elif isinstance(data, dict):
--> 468             mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    469         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    470             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype)
    281             arr if not is_datetime64tz_dtype(arr) else arr.copy() for arr in arrays
    282         ]
--> 283     return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    284 
    285 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in arrays_to_mgr(arrays, arr_names, index, columns, dtype, verify_integrity)
     76         # figure out the index, if necessary
     77         if index is None:
---> 78             index = extract_index(arrays)
     79         else:
     80             index = ensure_index(index)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in extract_index(data)
    395             lengths = list(set(raw_lengths))
    396             if len(lengths) > 1:
--> 397                 raise ValueError("arrays must all be same length")
    398 
    399             if have_dicts:

ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

Why is python not allowing me to describe the iris dataset?

Answer (score 2):

`iris` is a [Bunch](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.Bunch.html) (a dict-like), while `.describe` will only work with pandas dataframes; try:

```
iris = datasets.load_iris()
df_iris = pd.DataFrame(iris['data'], columns=iris['feature_names'])

df_iris.describe()
```

Output:

```
       sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)  petal length (cm)  petal width (cm)
count         150.000000        150.000000         150.000000        150.000000
mean            5.843333          3.057333           3.758000          1.199333
std             0.828066          0.435866           1.765298          0.762238
min             4.300000          2.000000           1.000000          0.100000
25%             5.100000          2.800000           1.600000          0.300000
50%             5.800000          3.000000           4.350000          1.300000
75%             6.400000          3.300000           5.100000          1.800000
max             7.900000          4.400000           6.900000          2.500000
```

Try also `iris.keys()`.